# Can't create a screenshot of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot of the screen using Java, I have the following code:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Visualizer {
    public static final void makeScreenshot(JFrame argFrame) {
        Rectangle rec = argFrame.getBounds();
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(rec.width, rec.height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        argFrame.paint(bufferedImage.getGraphics());

        try {
            // Create temp file.
            File temp = File.createTempFile("screenshot", ".png");

            // Use the ImageIO API to write the bufferedImage to a temporary file
            ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", temp);

            // Delete temp file when program exits.
            temp.deleteOnExit();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } // catch
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        makeScreenshot(window);
    }
}
```

But it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0

Comment: do you want desktop  scrrenshot? or jframe screenshot?

Comment: In your example, the window hasn't yet been sized to anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works:

1) Get image from a frame

```
public static BufferedImage getFrameImage(JFrame argFrame){
    int w = argFrame.getWidth();
    int h = argFrame.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    argFrame.paint(g);
    paint(g);
    return bi;
}
```

2) Save that image:

```
public static final void makeScreenshot(JFrame argFrame) {
    try {
        // Create temp file.
        File temp = File.createTempFile("screenshot", ".png");

        // Use the ImageIO API to write the bufferedImage to a temporary file
        ImageIO.write(getFrameImage(argFrame), "png", temp);

        // Delete temp file when program exits.
        temp.deleteOnExit();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    } // catch
}
```

But seeing your code, I didn't see nothing wrong. It will be probably an issue related with the JFrame, which maybe never has been set to visible, or pack(), and maybe it has not defined height and width yet.

so better Place some JLabel or panel on the JFrame window to ensure that it's size won't be 0.
Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello Everyone!!");

    panel.add(label);
    window.add(panel);

    window.setVisible(true);
    window.pack();
    makeScreenshot(window);
}
```

Comment: Generally `print` or `printAll` is a better method to use the `paint`, it's can disable double buffering and also avoids some other issues related to painting.  Also don't forget to dispose of the `Graphics` context when you done with, (in the past) I've had issues with it consuming memory and never getting GC'd

Answer (score 1):

the problem is your frame dimension return 0.when you call `rec.width()` .it returns 0 .same for height.but if you call `setVisible(true)` then rectangle has correct values.actually your rectangle is empty rectangle .`java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=0,height=0]`

to fix this;

call `setVisible(true)`

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.setVisible(true);
makeScreenshot(window);
```

also if you call

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
window.pack();
makeScreenshot(window);
```

it also work

Answer (score 0):

From `JFrame#getBounds()` (or rather, `Component#getBounds()`)' [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getBounds%28%29):

> The bounds specify this component's width, height, and location relative to its parent.

Focus on **relative to its parent**: this may imply negative values or `0`.

In turn, initializing a `BufferedImage` with negative values for width / height will throw `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: It looks like the width and height given here are both 0, no? That's what the exception says...